# DRF nested serializer supports empty field

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

First apologize if it's a bad title, I'm facing a problem with nested serializers but not very sure what is the root cause of it.

Here are my models,

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import CharField

class AssociatedService(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    association = models.ForeignKey('Association', null=True, related_name='associated_service')


class Association(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    uri = models.URLField()
    service = models.ForeignKey('Service', null=True, related_name='associations')    

class Service(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    uri = models.URLField();
```

Serializers,

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from bi_pod.models import Service, AssociatedService, Association


class AssociatedServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AssociatedService

class AssociationsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    associated_service = AssociatedServiceSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Association

    def create(self, validated_data):      
        associated_service_data = validated_data.pop('associated_service')
        associated_service = AssociatedServiceSerializer(data=associated_service_data, partial=True)
        if associated_service.is_valid():
            associated_service_obj = associated_service.save()
            assoication = Association.objects.create(**validated_data)
            assoication.associated_service.add(associated_service_obj)     
            return assoication


class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    associations = AssociationsSerializer(required=False, many=False)    
    class Meta:
        model = Service
```

The behavior is to POST service without association first. Once the service is in db, I'll post the association and add that to corresponding service.

The problem is that if I have `associations = AssociationsSerializer(required=False, many=False)` in my serializer, then following code will fail,

```
service_serializer = ServiceSerializer(data=request.data, partial=True)
if service_serializer.is_valid():
    service_serializer.save()
response_data = service_serializer.data
```

specifically when tring to call `service_serializer.data` that there will be exception `Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field id on serializer AssociationsSerializer.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the RelatedManager instance.
Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'id'.`

I traced into DRF code and found it will try to get `id` attribute from `RelatedManager` and apparently there is no serializer attribute inside the manager. So I'm wondering what should I do for such circumstances? Really appreciate help!

Answer (score 3):

Your `associations` field should be has `many = True`. Because you want to serialize multiple `associations` not just one. Remember that a `Service` instance in your model may have one or more `association` poiting him.

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    associations = AssociationsSerializer(required=False, many=True)    
    class Meta:
        model = Service
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. But what if there can only be one association with one service. Should I use a OneToOne instead?

Comment: @Derek yes. use OneToOne

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. However I think the general question I have is that for a serializer that has a RelatedManager field in it, how can I initialize the serializer from an object that doesn't have the related object yet?